# Excel 2010 - conditional formatting a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

Imagine I have column A, with **several rows** containing dates (eg. `2015-04-01`).

Then I have a column B, adding `+15` to column A (eg. `2015-04-16`).

I want column B to show conditional formatting:

- yellow if row from column A is `> 15` days from today;
- and red if column A is `> 20` days from today

eg (yellow):

```
column A - 2015-05-01
today()  - 2015-05-20
column B - 2015-05-16 (yellow)
```

eg (red):

```
column A - 2015-04-03
today()  - 2015-05-20
column B - 2015-04-18 (red)
```

Anyone knows how I can I do this in Excel?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ribbon/Home/Conditional Formatting/New Rule/Use a formula...

```
=A1<TODAY() - 15
```

(Changing A! to your selection, getting rid of $ signs)

Format how you want.

Add similar for the 20 rule.